# Simplifying O(nm) and O(n + m) time complexity

Tags: javascript, algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, big-o

If I have a function that runs in `O(nm)` time complexity, is it common practice/acceptable to simplify that into just saying it runs in `O(n^2)` time complexity?  For example, a function like this:

```
function funcOne(nArray, mArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nArray.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < mArray.length; j++) {

            ....

        }
    }
}
```

Also, if I have a function that runs in `O(n + m)` time complexity, is it common practice/acceptable to simplify that into just saying it runs in `O(n)` time complexity?  For example, a function like this:

```
function funcOne(nArray, mArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nArray.length; i++) {

        ...

    }

    for (var j = 0; j < mArray.length; j++) {

        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Only if `n` is an asymptotically linear function of `m`.

Comment: Big-O has a strict mathematical definition, you can't just swap out variables as you see fit.

Comment: sometimes you see "in O(n²) where n = max(a, b)" or "n > m w.l.o.g". But in most cases you would explicitly state the runtime complexity as a result of all inputs O(mn).

Answer (score -1):

The sample you're provided is about O(N) complexity because the loops are executed sequentially. In case you put one loop into another it is O(N^2) complexity. What about n and m? For sure, if there is a relation between n and m, expressing N via n and m can be a tricky thing. For simplicity, you can think about N as an average of n and m, i.e. N = (n+m)/2